# Help me I cannot link my font-awesome to my Wordpress Theme. I have my font-awesome folder already in my project

Tags: php, css, html

My Path: C:\Users.......\Desktop......\coding\font-awesome-4.7.0\css

my header code:

GTCoding

```
<div id="slideout-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog'); ?>">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects'); ?>">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/about'); ?>">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<nav>
    <div id="logo-img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="GTCoding Logo"> 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>"
                    <?php if(is_front_page()) echo 'class="active"' ?>
                >Home</a>
            
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog'); ?>"
                <?php if(get_post_type() == 'post') echo 'class="active"' ?>
                >Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects'); ?>"
                <?php if(get_post_type() == 'project') echo 'class="active"' ?>>Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/about'); ?>"
                <?php if(is_page('about') == 'post') echo 'class="active"' ?>
                >About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="search-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav> 

<div id="searchbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
</div> 

<?php if(is_front_page()); { ?>
   <main> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. To include FA you should look into enqueueing custom styles. Rather than just editing the header, you enqueue using functions.php to ensure that your stylesheet gets added at the right place. FA is more than just one stylesheet though so you might want to consider just using an FA WP plugin that handles all the @font-face etc. for you.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Search for Font Awesome on the plugin repo: https://wordpress.org/plugins/